# Using a constructor to initialize properties in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, constructor, java-ee-6

I have a doubt about using the constructor to initialize lists and other fields when using JPA, specifically my question is as follows:

Suppose I have an entity bean, that has lots of @OneToMany relationships, I would like to use the constructor to initialize them, so that I don't have to use statements like this in my controllers:

```
myEntity=new MyEntity();
myEntity.innerList=new ArrayList<Type>();
myEntity.innerList.add(newObject);
```

so instead I would have:

```
public MyEntity(){
 innerList=new ArrayList<Type>();
}
```

Now, the question is... will JPA call this constructor when mapping properties from the database?. I mean If I had persisted before an entire list, will the constructor run and reinitialize my entites lists?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, JPA will call the no-arg constructor of your entity. After that, your lists will be replaced by specific List implementations of your JPA engine. These lists allow lazy-loading and other functionalities needed by the JPA engine.

I wouldn't care much about the needless `ArrayList` instantiation in this case. This is not where a typical JPA application will take the most time. I find it much more important to have clear invariants and to respect them. One of these invariants is : my entity always has a non-null list of other entities.

Comment: Is it possible to force JPA to use an args constructor? (e.g. I want to call a method after all the attributes have been loaded)

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, at least in Hibernate, when you `load()` an instance, in first place the no-argument constructor gets called, and afterwards, associations are assigned. As a matter of fact, those instances created within the constructor will be thrown away when JPA assigns the persisted collection/entities.

So, if this is what you are asking, it is safe to use these initializations on the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JPA will call your no-argument constructor (creating an empty ArrayList) and will then set `innerList` to the values from the databases (by accessing the field or calling the setter, depending on your configuration).